# Count Analysis Number Step -1 to 0 (1/2, 2/3 and 3/3)

Tags: vb.net

how can I make this code work? Let's say we have in Textbox1 - the following: (2,4,6) - the textbox that will be scanned to determine the analysis.

```
TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(0) = 3,6,7,9
TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(1) = 2,6,9,10
TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(2) = 3,5,7,10
```

then it will result: >

and if exists count reset to 0, if not exists count +1. the analysis will begin from the last line to the first line. TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(2) - and finish with TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(0)

```
1/3 - 0 (because one value exists 2 or 4 or 6, in TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(0), 
2/3 - 1 (because not not 2/3 - 2,6 or 4,6) and +1 add to value. 
3/3 - 3 (because not 3/3 - 2,4,6) and +1 add to value.
```

so briefly, an analysis, 1/3, 2/3 and 3/3, if the value exists then it will be 0, if the value does not exist, it will be added + 1. It has to start from Step -1 to Line 1. I'm trying to make this code, and I'm not doing worked it.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim lastDraw1 As Integer = 0    '1/3
        Dim lastDraw2 As Integer = 0    '2/3
        Dim lastDraw3 As Integer = 0    '3/3
        For i As Integer = Step to -1 To TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines.Count - 0
            Dim lineVals As String() = TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(i).Split(",")
            Select Case lineVals.Count()
                Case 1
                    lastDraw1 = 0
                    lastDraw2 += 1
                    lastDraw3 += 1
                    TextBox1.Text = lastDraw1
                    TextBox2.Text = lastDraw2
                    TextBox3.Text = lastDraw3
                Case 2
                    lastDraw1 = 0
                    lastDraw2 = 0
                    lastDraw3 += 1
                    TextBox1.Text = lastDraw1
                    TextBox2.Text = lastDraw2
                    TextBox3.Text = lastDraw3
                Case 3
                    lastDraw1 = 0
                    lastDraw2 = 0
                    lastDraw3 = 0
                    TextBox1.Text = lastDraw1
                    TextBox2.Text = lastDraw2
                    TextBox3.Text = lastDraw3
                Case Else
                    'This should probably also be handled
            End Select
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing but to fix the For...Next

```
    Dim StartIndex = TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines.Length - 1
    For i = StartIndex To 0 Step -1
        'Your code here
    Next
```